# Add authoriazation to react routers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have defined routers in my react application. I have a 3 pages in my application. After the user successfully logs in, it is taken to the next screens. Flow is working fine. But there is a problem. When I directly enter the url for other pages in my application, it loads that page regardless of whether user logged in or not. I want to add a check on this. If user is not logged in then he must be redirected to the login page.

These are my routes

```
<Route path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
        <Route path='app' component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/video-screen' component={VideoScreen}>
                <IndexRoute component={TagList}/>
                <Route path='/add' component={AddTags}/>
                <Route path='/TagList' component={TagList}/>
                <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
```

And this is my login component's method which checks the login credentials and take user to next page if login is successful

```
handleLoginButtonClick() {
        var that = this;
        let token;
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://www.backend.example.raccte.com/auth/login/",
            "method": "POST",
            "credentials": 'include',
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            "data": {
                "password": document.getElementById("password").value,
                "username": document.getElementById("username").value
            },
            success:( response, textStatus, jQxhr )=> {
                this.props.tokenAction(response.auth_token);
            }
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {

            token = response.auth_token

            console.log(token);
            this.context.router.push('/app')
        });
```

Updates

```
 function authorize(){
            if(window.localStorage.token == null){
                browserHistory.push('/')
            }
        }
    function getRoutes(store) {


        return (
            <Router>
                <Route path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
                <Route path='app' component={App} onEnter={this.authorize}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                    <Route path='/video-screen' component={VideoScreen}>
                        <IndexRoute component={TagList}/>
                        <Route path='/add' component={AddTags}/>
                        <Route path='/TagList' component={TagList}/>
                        <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
                    </Route>
                </Route>
            </Router>
        )
    }
    export default getRoutes;
```

gives me an error saying Uncaught ReferenceError: authorize is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Routes have an onEnter functionality you can use for this. Let's say you have a function to authorize it inside the component containing the React router stuff. You could do something like this (some pseudo code here):

```
authorize() {
    if (user is NOT authorized) browserHistory.push(login page)
}

<Route path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
    <Route path='app' component={App} onEnter={this.authorize}/>
</Router>
```

That way even if they enter the URL straight into the browser URL bar, the onEnter function is still called, and if they aren't logged in it will redirect them to the login page.

Comment: I usually just keep it as a function in the component where all the router stuff is being rendered

Comment: How should I check whether user is logged in or not?

Comment: You can have a boolean stored in state that tracks whether they're logged in or not. You can save it in the browser storage so it's still there on refresh (like when a site remembers you've logged in). If you're using plain React then you'd have to pass this 'authorized' boolean as a property across a lot of elements and down through routes, which can be annoying. This is a good example of when to use state management tools like redux, or jumpsuit. Makes stuff like this a lot easier

Comment: I am using react-redux to save the sates. So when I call the login api it gives me back a token. Now I store the token into my reducer. My doubt is everytime I ll refresh the page, say i go to login url, that state will be reset to null. Right? Does reducer saves the states even if i open the application in a new tab (say) ?

Comment: Ok cool so if you want your state to remain during page refresh there is middleware that does that that. Check out the redux-persist and redux-storage middleware. As for a new tab or say a whole new browser session I'm not 100% sure, there might be stuff for that. You'll have to do a bit of research for that tho, this is drifting a bit far from the original post

Comment: Instead of storing token to reducer use window.localstorage to store token

Comment: Also use json web token for a more secure token

Comment: Thanks I ll look into it

Comment: @Prakashsharma I am using json webtokens only. How can I make use of localStoerage

Comment: @Jayce444 I added authorize to my App component but I am getting an error in console saying "cannot read authorize of undefined". See my updates

Comment: When you get token from backend then first save that token to windows localstorage like - window.localstorage.mytoken = token and then redirect to app

Comment: Now in the authorize method above just check if window.localsrorage.mytoken exist and valid or not

Comment: When user signout then simply delete that token. Window localstorage remain even on refresh  and new tab

Comment: @Prakashsharma  Ok I ll try it. But can u please check my updates. I am getting an error. See if you could help in that so that I could try what u suggested

Comment: Move your authorize function to router file

Comment: @Prakashsharma Please look at the latest update of mine. When I go to App component's url directly without login, it doesn't redirect me to login page. In my login component I included window.localStorage.token = token;

Comment: Try logging the loacalstirage token on console in authorize method before if condition. Make sure it is null when user is log out.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is u declared your `authorize` method in `App` component, you need to declare it in the file where you defined all `routes`, like this:

```
function authorize(){
    console.log('hello');
} 

<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
    <Route path='app' component={App} onEnter={authorize}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/video-screen' component={VideoScreen}>
            <IndexRoute component={TagList}/>
            <Route path='/add' component={AddTags}/>
            <Route path='/TagList' component={TagList}/>
            <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: authorize is not defined'

Comment: it should be {this.authorize}

Comment: Your authorize function needs to be in the same component as all your router stuff. It doesn't look like it is, based on the code in your post

Comment: @Jayce444 I did. Check the latest update. Still getting error.

Comment: Ok I got it. Works now.

Comment: @Jayce444 i was just telling the way it should be, didn't wrote the complete code, basic template :)

Comment: @ApurvG issue is `window.localStorage.token==null` is not true, replace null with undefined, because if any key is not present in localstorage it will return undefined not null, it will work :)

Comment: Still it loads the app page. Not redirected

Comment: @ApurvG do one thing, put the console inside if condition and check whether its going inside or not, one more thing, in ur update code u didn't defined `history='browserHistory'`  with router ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134892/discussion-between-apurvg-and-mayank-shukla).

Answer (score 1):

I use Higher-Order Components for this check this exemple

**RequireAuth**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'



export default function (ComposedCmponent) {
class RequireAuth extends Component {
componentWillMount () {
   //we need to check if user is authenticated before the component will mount 
  //here i check if the user is authenticated i'm using JWT authentification for this exemple, usually i use local storage to save the token and we can check the validation of the token 
  //If the user is not authenticated we redirect to /login 
  let validtoken = window.localStorage.getItem('id_token')
  if (!this.props.isAuthenticated || !validtoken) {
    this.context.router.push('/login')
  }
}

componentWillUpdate (nexProps) {
  // we need to the same as we did in componentWillMount
  // in case component will update the use not authenticated 
  //If the user is not authenticated we redirect to /login 
  if (this.props.isAuthenticated !== nexProps.isAuthenticated) {
    if (!nexProps.isAuthenticated) {
      this.context.router.push('/login')
    }
  }
}

render () {
  //now the user is authenticated we render the component passed by     HOC component 
  return (
    <ComposedCmponent {...this.props} />
  )
}
}
```

and if i want secure a path i use  my `HOC RequireAuth` in my router

```
 <Route path='/' component={App}>
  <Route path='/dashboard' component={requireAuth(Dashboard)} /> 
</Route>
```

Comment: Sorry i cannot understand anything from this code snippet. can you please explain it to me in detail. ?

Comment: Can you please make it in reference to my components names. I am getting confused. Also where to put this component? Would be a great help man. Thanks.